How to register multiple Flurl clients in DI container?
Flurl documentation says that the recommended approach for Flurl clients using DI is to utilize this registration pattern:
// at service registration:
services.AddSingleton<IFlurlClientCache>(sp => new FlurlClientCache()
    .Add("MyCli", "https://some-api.com"));


However, this doesn't work if I need to repeat this code several times and register several clients into the DI container.
Of course, I could chain many Add() methods and populate one cache with clients, but this is not always possible. Probable use-case - registration of different clients from different libraries.
Do you have any clues how to overcome this and properly register only one singleton IFlurlClientCache with multiple clients from multiple places in the code?

You're on the right track with GetOrAdd (per your self-answer), but you don't have to give up using DI to manage a singleton cache. It should end up looking more like this:
// register the cache but don't add clients to it yet
services.AddSingleton<IFlurlClientCache>(sp => new FlurlClientCache()
   .WithDefaults(b => {
        ...
    }));

public class MyService
{
    private static readonly IFlurlClient _flurlClient;

    public MyService(IFlurlClientCache flurlCache) {
        _flurlClient = flurlCache.GetOrAdd(serviceName, baseUri, configure);
    }
}

Even if the service above is registered as a transient, the named client will only get created and configured at most once, since the the cache is registered as a singleton.

My problem has been solved by adding static FlurlClientCache instance registration to DI:
services.TryAddSingleton(sp => FlurlHttp.Clients.WithDefaults(b =>
{
    // Common defaults for all clients which uses DI container
    var contextAccessor = sp.GetRequiredService<ICorrelationContextAccessor>();
    var options = Options.Create(new CorrelateClientOptions { RequestHeader = "X-Correlation-ID" });
    b.AddMiddleware(() => new CorrelatingHttpMessageHandler(contextAccessor, options));
}));

// Add new named FlurlClient to FlurlClientCache
FlurlHttp.Clients.GetOrAdd(serviceName, baseUri, configure);

and re-using this code multiple times for every client.
Please feel free to advise me better solution if you find one.

Your answer is basically correct. GetOrAdd is thread-safe way to ensure that a client of the given name is only created and configured once. So if your configure method does a lot of heavy lifting, you can rest assured it will only get called once per unique serviceName for the lifetime of your application.

Also note that FlurlHttp.Clients is a global static instance of FlurlClientCache. You could have still used DI here if you prefer a DI-managed singleton - just register IFlurlClientCache as you did in your question but don't "Add" any clients to it at the time. Instead, inject the cache into your services and call GetOrAdd on the cache from there.
